# Unable to use ADB via USB

Tags: android, debugging, usb, motorola

I am trying to connect to my device(Moto G 4 plus) to my windows machine using usb wire. But I am unable to usb adb on it while i have connected to it. But I am able to use adb while I have connected to it via adb over Wifi

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already have this installed:

[image: Android sdk]

Also check if you have developer funcionality on your device enabled.